# illustrator export as html

Tags: svg, icons, adobe-illustrator

My svg icons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 181.44 71.99">
  <rect x="1.6" y=".5" width="179.34" height="16.7" rx="8.35" ry="8.35" style="fill: #1d1d1b; stroke: #1d1d1b; stroke-miterlimit: 10;"/>
  <rect x=".5" y="28.63" width="179.34" height="16.7" rx="8.35" ry="8.35" style="fill: #1d1d1b; stroke: #1d1d1b; stroke-miterlimit: 10;"/>
  <rect x=".5" y="54.79" width="179.34" height="16.7" rx="8.35" ry="8.35" style="fill: #1d1d1b; stroke: #1d1d1b; stroke-miterlimit: 10;"/>
</svg>
```

Boostrap svg icons

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-1-square-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2Zm7.283 4.002V12H7.971V5.338h-.065L6.072 6.656V5.385l1.899-1.383h1.312Z"/>
</svg>
```

Question: how to export icons like in boostrap (single element) not like me (separated elements)

I use patch: file > export as.. > svg format

Comment: You need to convert your elements to a [compound path](https://illustratorhow.com/compound-path/)

Comment: problem solve, thanks for help!